# Countdown for a specific date

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a countdown program. But my problem is that I cant get the

```
getElementsByClassName
```

to work (in my opinion). The WHOLE program will work if I use

```
getElementById
```

and change the HTML tags with id=""...

My whole code is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/f1kzL78h/5/

I need the class-function because I will have more p-tags in the future in my HTML-file, and I want to apply Javascript to all my classes that have the same name.

HTML:

```
<p class="date">2019-04-13</p>
<p class="time">21:21</p>
<p class="appear"></p>
```

JS:

```
var articleDate = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
var articleTime = document.getElementsByClassName("time");

var total = articleDate + 'T' + articleTime + ':00';

var countDownTime = new Date(total).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

    var difference = countDownTime - timeNow;

    var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    res = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

     document.getElementsByClassName("appear") = res;

}, 1000);
```

I appreciate all help i can get.

Comment: `var total = articleDate + 'T' + articleTime + ':00';`  <- what exactly are you expecting to happen here? Also `document.getElementsByClassName("appear") = res;` isn't valid for many reasons. See [manipulating documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) from the MDN. And especially [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

## Elements by class

`document.getElementsByClassName("appear")` returns a collection of elements. You can iterate it with the following code

```
const appears = document.getElementsByClassName("appear");
for (var i = 0; i < appears.length; i++) {
  appears.item(i).innerHTML = res;
}
```

## Get dates from HTML

You were using `var articleDate = document.getElementsByClassName("date");` which is not returning the expected value

You should use `var articleDate = document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0].innerHTML;` to get the value inside your element

## Implementation in your case

```js
// Fångar upp information om artiklens datum och tid

var articleDate = document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0].innerHTML;
var articleTime = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML;

var total = articleDate + 'T' + articleTime + ':00';

var countDownTime = new Date(total).getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

  var difference = countDownTime - timeNow;
  
  var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  res = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  const appears = document.getElementsByClassName("appear");
  for (var i = 0; i < appears.length; i++) {
    appears.item(i).innerHTML = res;
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="date">2019-04-13</p>
<p class="time">21:21</p>
<p class="appear"></p>
```

Comment: Why does the output show: -7042:-12:-22:-55 ? I have the date 2019-04-13. Today it's 2019-04-12 (Europe). I should get +, not -

Answer (score 0):

Change code like this. Use document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0].textContent for getting value.

```js
// Fångar upp information om artiklens datum och tid
var articleDate = document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0].textContent;
var articleTime = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].textContent;

var total = articleDate + 'T' + articleTime + ':00';

var countDownTime = new Date(total).getTime();


var x = setInterval(function() {

  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

  var difference = countDownTime - timeNow;
  
  var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  res = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  document.getElementsByClassName("appear")[0].textContent = res;

}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="date">2019-04-13</p>
<p class="time">21:21</p>
<p class="appear"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I need the class-function because I will have more p-tags in the
>   future in my HTML-file, and I want to apply Javascript to all my
>   classes that have the same name."

I did a little modification to give you an idea. I think this can be your start point to create a countdown for many elements:

```
<p class="date">2019-04-13</p>
<p class="time">21:21</p>
<p class="appear"></p>

<p class="date">2019-04-13</p>
<p class="time">10:21</p>
<p class="appear"></p>

setInterval(function() {
  var articleElements = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
  for(var i = 0; i < articleElements.length; i++) {
    var articleDate = articleElements[i].innerText;
    var articleTime = articleElements[i].nextElementSibling.innerText;
    var total = articleDate + 'T' + articleTime + ':00';
    var countDownTime = new Date(total).getTime();

    var elAppear = articleElements[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    elAppear.setAttribute('data-countdown', countDownTime);

    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
      var difference = countDownTime - timeNow;
      var days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      res = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    elAppear.innerText = res;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: In the proposed code you are re-performing the calculation in each iteration while it is the same algorithm. You should extract this outside of the loop

Comment: @Weedoze thank you for your comment but as I said "it's just start point"

Comment: Thank you so much @MarceloVismari. I needed this one too because I have a for loop in my HTML-file which generates several <p> tags with each classnames. I am doing this through Python and Flask. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Change to `document.getElementsByClassName("appear")[0].innerHTML = res;`

Also update for

```
var articleDate = document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0].innerHTML;
var articleTime = document.getElementsByClassName("time")[0].innerHTML;
```

Because `document.getElementsByClassName("appear")` only DOM element, and `document.getElementsByClassName` return array of element, need innerHTML to get value.
https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/8mxh0zkr/3/

Comment: I've tried this few times. But the problem here is that I get a wrong output, for ex. -7042:-12:-20, but that is not true in my case

Comment: I get it @HienNguyen . But i don't understand why this does not work in my code when I am not running it from JsFiddle?

Comment: Edit: solved. Thank you for the easy solution @HienNguyen